Method for detecting an auto page break - pyfpdf
I am designing a tool to display a git repository's commits in PDF form with pyfpdf.
It have designed it so that each commit only spans across one page if possible. However, if a commit is longer than a page, I simply draw it and allow FPDF to handle the page breaking for me. This is fine when I am generating the PDF in light mode, but when doing it in dark mode, all the pages that were automatically broken to when generating a multipage commit are not picked up by my program, so I don't know when to draw a custom dark page background.
Some code to explain what I would like to add to fix my problem:
def page_break_callback(pdf):
    pdf.draw_dark_page_bg()

pdf = FPDF()
draw_commit(long_commit_description) # This will call page_break_callback


While writing my question, I realised I could try implementing some kind of callback, and I found a solution. I will show an example below:
from fpdf import FPDF
dark_mode = True

def _beginpage_addon(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.set_fill_colour((51, 51, 51)) # Dark theme background
        self.rect(h=self.h, w=self.w, x=0, y=0, style="DF")
        return result
    return wrapper

if dark_mode:
    FPDF._beginpage = _beginpage_addon(FPDF._beginpage) # Add the wrapper to the FPDF class

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.multi_cell(long_commit) # Any extra pages will be dark!

Not sure if this is the best or most safe way to do it, but it works.
